# Python Concatenante Integer and String then make variable as integer format

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to concatenate string and integer together following this format.

integer should be `0x0` and the string format is about `00001H` I want to concatenate them and the return variable should be integer format. so it should be `0x00001` since i'm removing the last string to retain only the numeric one.

I already tried using `.format()` and `%s` but doesn't have the luck of making it works.

This is the code i already tried

```
hex_offset = driver_data['hex_offset'].rstrip('H')
#hex_offset = 00001
address_start = 0x0

new_address = 0x0 + "()".format(hex_offset)
print(new_address)
```

my expectation result should be `0x000001`

Thank you

Comment: It's not really clear how you want to put the integer and string together. Could you provide some more examples?

Comment: `I already tried [...]`: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: added some codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `address_start` is equal to `0x0`, you should store it in form of `string`. `0x0` is read as an integer in hexadecimal form because of the prefix `0x`. Also using `()` with `format` will print `()` instead of `hex_offset`. You should be using `'{}'.format(hex_offset)`.

```py
new_address = '0x0' + '{}.format(hex_offset)
```

Comment: i need it to read as integer. so how may i able to read it as integer?

Comment: you can't concatenate string and integer together, unless you convert integer to string. I am assuming in the end, you want to convert these hexadecimal number to integer. One way to go about that would be to convert `new_address` string into integer using `int('0x0001', base=0)`

Comment: making it base = 0 will only give me a result of single numeric integer

Comment: you can pass different base value as well, but when you pass `base = 0`, `int` will infer the base from the prefix of string